# Angular 1.6 many instances of the same component on a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I have a component inside an `ng-repeat`, and sometimes it creates a really big number of components (over 1000), causing a significant delay (several seconds) on page load. Profiler shows that all code that causes noticeable delay is executed inside angular or angular-select (which is used by my custom component), so it's not related to my code, although it might be related to some watches that I'm setting.

What is the common way of dealing with this? Is it possible to initialize a component only once and create multiple instances without calling the same code thousands of times?

Comment: *Is it possible to initialize a component only once and create multiple instances* No. Modify the components to not use data binding if possible. Don't display 1000 components at once. Use custom solutions instead of ng-repeat. This is how it is usually done.

Comment: please share your code. How you added the watch

Comment: use pagination or smth like that, why to show 1000 components?

Comment: @estus I think your comment should be the answer.

Comment: Sure, if you think that it really answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually a component cannot be initialized once and cloned. It would be possible for purely static component, but compilation wouldn't be a bottleneck for this case.

When there's a significant number of component/directive instances that should be necessarily displayed simultaneously, they have to be modified to not use data binding if possible, or use one-time watchers. This way watchers count stays within a desirable limit (usually ~1000 watchers).

Custom solutions can be used instead of ng-repeat for performance boost. And 1000 components preferably shouldn't be displayed at once.

There are several  infinite scroll solutions for Angular that limit the items to the ones that are shown in visible area.